# ¿ Cómo calcular en Python usando Numpy la moda ( estadísticas, moda, media, mediana) de un array?

Tags: python, array, pandas, numpy, estadística

He hallado media y mediana. Pero la moda no se como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay en `numpy` una función que te dé la moda. Pero puedes usar [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), en la biblioteca estándar python, para encontrar el valor con más repeticiones, pues esa es la definición de moda. (tendrás que usar `matriz.flatten()` para reducir tu matriz bidimensional a una lista de valores, que es lo que `Counter()` necesita)

Answer (score 3):

Con numpy no hay función que calcule la moda. Puedes usar el paquete de statistics que ya viene instalado en python, o usar scipy.

Usando statistics sería asi:

```
import statistics as stat

edades = [21, 17, 89, 76, 32, 21, 45, 21, 89, 21, 15, 89, 21]

moda=stat.mode(edades)

print(moda)
```

En este caso la moda es 21.

Y usando scipy sería así:

```
from scipy import stats as st

edades = [21, 17, 89, 76, 32, 21, 45, 21, 89, 21, 15, 89, 21]

moda=st.mode(edades)

print(moda)
```

El resultado es:
`ModeResult(mode=array([21]), count=array([5]))`
Que quiere decir que el valor que más se repite es 21 con un total de 5 veces.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, con esas librerias veo como sacar en un array la moda, pero ¿ para el Dataframe que pongo donde hay que sacar para varias columnas me da errores. Al final lo hice con lo de flatten. Lo puse todo en un solo vector y pude, pero ¿era necesario?, ¿Se puede hacer de una sola vez sobre el DataFrame?